# Modifying the java code generated by adding a break line before each new section

Tags: java, eclipse, abstract-syntax-tree, line-breaks

how can i add a break line before each new Section in a java source code automatically?. My java source code is generated automatically and it is made of 5 sections. i must create a new java class, this class will use the sources generated to modify it and have an other java source file totaly abstract to the users
thank you for you answers

Comment: What tool are you using to generate the code?

Comment: it's an auther language. You can say a meta language

Comment: Show some code, give us more information. Otherwise it's not possible to answer your question.

Comment: each file is a class which contains an enum déclaration a constructor of the class and other enum déclarations.

Comment: ASTs are orthogonal to layout, that is, whitespace and line breaks.  You need to prettyprint an AST to have such an opportunity.  What are you using to build the AST, and what do you expect to use to prettyprint the AST?

Comment: *"I want.."*  I want an ice-cream, a nice, big ice-cream.  But that is not relevant to this site, nor is what you want.  Did you have a question?

Comment: i don't know how can i add a break line to the Java code, i supposed that ASTs is the unique manner to do it and to modify a java code. sorry but pretty print an AST, what does it mean ? thanks for yor help

Comment: sorry Andrew Thompson but it 's the first time that i use this forum and i don't control english well. So sorry

Comment: @AndrewThompson - no ice cream for you.  Only Jon Skeet gets ice cream. :-)

Comment: @user1369630  There is no need to be sorry, but there is a good cause to ***add a question.***  You know, one of those sentences ending in '?' - you have already managed to ask questions in comments, so it seems obvious you are capable of it.  *"don't control english well"* If I in any way cared that your English (or mine, for that matter) was not 'perfect' I might have pointed out that *"générated to modifie"*  should be *"generated to modify"*.  I did not mention it since it was clear as typed, and also ***not the point.***

Answer (score 0):

Formatting stuff (like white space) is not encoded in a typical AST, and unless you can change the classes that represent your ASTs, you won't be able to add it.

Your simplest option is to modify the generator code (or templates) that are used to render the ASTs to Java source code.  Get them to add the extra lines at each "section".  (This presupposes that the generator / templates can figure out where the section boundaries are at the AST level.)

Comment: thank you Stephen C. I do my training/internship, and they say that it 'is not possible to modifiy the générator. I must créate a new classe whom let me to do this for all java source générated and it will be asked (the class) for each time a new source créated or an old file modified

Comment: Well, it *seems* like this particular task (adding blank lines to the generated code) *might be* impossible.  Of course, this depends on what the AST classes look like, and how the generator works ...